# How to analyze movie titles?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, feature-selection

I want to predict movie gross collections using data that is available before release, eg title, actors, director, studio, critic ratings, genre, etc. I found a way to numerically quantify most of these, but could not quantify title. The title conveys much useful information, such as if the movie is a sequel, length of title, sentiment associated, etc. How to extract these information quantitatively from title?

Comment: this not much related to what do to with the title, but Noah Smith published something interesting in the same topic, predict revenue based on critics:

http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~nasmith/papers/joshi+das+gimpel+smith.naacl10.pdf

Comment: This is a question that requires a research. Get a huge amount of movies' titles and reviews and try to figure a way to use them both for your problem. In general names contain capitals so it might be a good lead to your problem. In addition the words that surround the movie title might be the same for different movies so this is something worth a check, word2vec might be relevant for finding surrounding words. Good luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BoWs are the standard way to create text based features, though I wouldn't recommend it since movie titles are short and many of them contains out of context words, named entity.. which will make your feature vector even more sparse.

You can create a word2vec encoding of each word of the title and then take the mean vector of the title as your feature. My favorite tools to do it: [gensim](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/word2vec.html) or [Facebook fast Text](https://github.com/facebookresearch/fastText)

Comment: Or else the OP can use Doc2Vec.